# How to start a sleeping powershell on Google Kubernetes Engine with Beta Windows containers/nodes?

Tags: windows, kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine

I can't seem to figure out why a pod as simple as

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: win-test
spec:
  containers:
    - name: shell
      image: "mcr.microsoft.com/windows/servercore:1809"
      command:
        - powershell
      args:
        - "Start-Sleep"
        - "999999"
      imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
  nodeSelector:
    kubernetes.io/os: windows
```

fails to start due to

`failed to start container "4f4e02205101779ffef6e6bad6f7bc8d94da1dafa4173de5b87bb3a98508c776": Error response from daemon: CreateComputeSystem 4f4e02205101779ffef6e6bad6f7bc8d94da1dafa4173de5b87bb3a98508c776: The system cannot find the file specified. (extra info: {"SystemType":"Container","Name":"4f4e02205101779ffef6e6bad6f7bc8d94da1dafa4173de5b87bb3a98508c776","Owner":"docker","VolumePath":"\\\\?\\Volume{852ddcc4-3819-442f-8748-ab95850656ee}","IgnoreFlushesDuringBoot":true,"LayerFolderPath":"C:\\ProgramData\\docker\\windowsfilter\\4f4e02205101779ffef6e6bad6f7bc8d94da1dafa4173de5b87bb3a98508c776","Layers":[{"ID":"f19b83e5-b168-56b9-aadd-5aa5ded15656","Path":"C:\\ProgramData\\docker\\windowsfilter\\a2c514d945fb21b87e5188e8df2ac52d95d727e2c9081a526719b1a0cc504403"},{"ID":"e3aef991-6354-522e-8f9e-f68a75bbf653","Path":"C:\\ProgramData\\docker\\windowsfilter\\8a82b1f3ce35668195c9f27a15736f0b1c20cd3fcb1f99341ec56db5ce7775f1"}],"ProcessorWeight":5000,"HostName":"win-test","MappedDirectories":[{"HostPath":"c:\\var\\lib\\kubelet\\pods\\87884b53-b09b-4ec3-87e6-6cec2e1c9d43\\volumes\\kubernetes.io~secret\\default-token-nk777","ContainerPath":"c:\\var\\run\\secrets\\kubernetes.io\\serviceaccount","ReadOnly":true,"BandwidthMaximum":0,"IOPSMaximum":0,"CreateInUtilityVM":false}],"HvPartition":false,"NetworkSharedContainerName":"b84c2337fa12b3d9f7228bba3c7d0c0a321270df6c693da0bb4b08e35366b6ea"}): RunContainerError`

I'm expecting the container in the pod to start a powershell which then lives for 999999 seconds before the container succeeds.

I'm using a GKE Beta Cluster 1.16.4-gke.22.

Comment: Maybe `The system cannot find the file specified` could be the problem. I will try to reproduce and return asap.

Comment: @rabello Thanks for you input. I tried `WINDOWS_LTSC` instead of `WINDOWS_SAC` in the meantime and it works with LTSC. However I'd be interested in understanding what goes wrong with SAC and whether it's a bug that might be worth reporting. I'd be grateful if you could verify that it works with LTSC and you could write an answer if it does.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**TL;DR**

just switch the container image version to newer one, 1903:

```
"mcr.microsoft.com/windows/servercore:1903"
```

**Longer story:**

Your container image version must match with container host version, which is not in your  case (please read the principales that describe it on MS sites, [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/virtualization/windowscontainers/deploy-containers/version-compatibility?tabs=windows-server-1909%2Cwindows-10-1909#matching-container-host-version-with-container-image-versions), including practical examples)

Currently you are trying to run container image with OS Version: `10.0.17763.*` on top of container host with OS Version: `10.0.18363.*` - I assume your Windows worker nodes are based on windows-server-1909 VM image.

Please check [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/pl-pl/windows-server/get-started/windows-server-release-info#windows-server-current-versions-by-servicing-option) for general OS Version/OS Build mapping of current Windows Server versions.

If you really need to run this specific container image version (1809) of MS Server Core, spin up another worker nodes basing on older (matching) VM image version.

Answer (score 1):

@Nepomucen's answer is correct.
I wanted to add that you can use image "mcr.microsoft.com/windows/servercore/iis:latest", which is multi-arch, and will work on all supported windows nodes (and should continue to work on newer arches when they are released).